# Integrating Axios Requests in Next.js 13 Server Components with Internationalization

Tags: next.js, server, internationalization, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js 13 project where I'm trying to utilize server components and Axios to handle HTTP requests. My project also requires internationalization and I'm currently facing difficulties getting everything to work together properly.

I'm working on the project that requires X-Accept-Language header to be set before request is sent from Server Components.

In the main Layout.tsx file I'm setting header on axios instance but it's sending request before setting that header.

```
export default async function LocaleLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: PageProps["params"]
}) {
  let messages
  try {
    messages = (await import(`../../messages/${params.locale}.json`)).default
  } catch (error) {
    notFound()
  }

  setLanguageHeader(params.locale)

  return (
```

in one of the child page.tsx I send a request

```
const { data } = await getParkingLots();
```

but it sends default language first and sends second request with correct header set.

this is my middleware.ts

```
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware"

export default createMiddleware({
  // A list of all locales that are supported
  locales: ["he", "en"],

  // If this locale is matched, pathnames work without a prefix (e.g. `/about`)
  defaultLocale: "he",
  localeDetection: false,
})

export const config = {
  // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)"],
}
```

and I'm using next-intl with Next 13.4.9 and axios.

Comment: can you share what getParkingLots looks like?